# Pause ASIHTTP QUEUE

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I'm using an `ASINetworkQueue` to download around 50 files in an iPad app. I'm looking for a way of allowing the user to `pause` and `resume` the queue.

The `ASIHTTP` docs refer to

> `[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];`

but this operates at an individual request level, not at the queue level. As `ASINetworkQueue` is a subclass of `NSOperationQueue` I've also tried

```
[queue setSuspended:YES];
```

and while this will pause a queue, it does not affect the downloads in progress, it just waits until they've finished and then pauses the queue, which in my case means many seconds between the user pressing the button and the queue actually pausing, which is not the UI experience I want.

Can anyone suggest another way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate your requests in queue and pause or resume them

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in [self.netWorkQueue operations]) {
   //your code
}
```